# Sending scheduled e-mail with Mandrill and Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel, smtp, mandrill

I am trying to schedule an e-mail to be sent in the future using Laravel with Mandrill SMTP.

This is what I am currently doing but nothing gets sent:

```
$mail= Mail::queue('emails.new', $data, function($message) use ($user) {
    $message
    ->to($user['email'], $user['firstname'])
    ->from('info@test.com', 'Sender')
    ->subject('Subject');

      $headers = $message->getHeaders();
      $headers->addTextHeader('X-MC-SendAt', $user['time']);
    });
```

$user['time'] is a timestamp in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format.

Comment: Does it work if you does not queue? (direct send)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at i time. I found this package [Mail To](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/abishekrsrikaanth/mailto#send-mandrill-time) and it worked like a charm. You can try this.